# Kronecker product $ n $ matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

I would like to write code to realize the Kronecker Product of $ n $  matrices, for instance when $ n=4 $ and the matrices are Pauli matrices

```
KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1]]
```

Is there a convenient way to first incorporate the general $ n $ in the code, so that I don't have to write the code each time I change $ n $?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Sequence[ ]` would be the go-to, but it flattens out the list.

Plan B: You can create a new operator that will 'fold' up the list.

Create the operator

```
kronk = Fold[KroneckerProduct];
```

Get your list of arbitrary length:

```
n = 4; res = Table[PauliMatrix[1], n];
```

Use your operator on the list

```
kronk[res] == KroneckerProduct[PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1], PauliMatrix[1]]
 (* True *)
```

Comment: @MilkY thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Apply (@@)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
kronkPauli[ind_List] := KroneckerProduct @@ PauliMatrix[ind]

kronkPauli[{1, 1, 1, 1}]
```

---

**Update**

Above `kronkPauli` accepts any combinations of `PauliMatrix`es (for $ i=0,1,2,3 $). But if you want only a couple of ones with $ i=1 $, the resultant matrix is just an antidiagonal one, with all $ 1 $s located at the antidiagonal positions.

For that special kind of matrixes, it can, at least, be realized by below two methods:

```
matrix[n_] := SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i + j == 2^n + 1 -> 1, 2^{n, n}]
matrix2[n_] := IdentityMatrix[2^n] // Reverse
```

Comment: Doh...must be a pathological thing with me and Apply[ ], just never use it much.

Comment: @MikeY Why it is so, may I ask?

Comment: Just a mental block, I guess. I think of a List as a fundamental data type that gets passed as an argument rather than the head of an expression that can be replaced to magically co-opt it. My loss, but I am working on it!

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for the same problem and I solved it in an easier way to perform the same task.

```
n = 4;
NUf = PauliMatrix[1];
For[i = 1, i <= n - 1, i++, {
  NUf = KroneckerProduct[NUf, PauliMatrix[1]];
  }]
```

the matrix form of the result
[image]